# laravel 5.2 carousel only in index page doesn't wok

Tags: laravel, file, indexing, carousel, display

I use laravel 5.2 and tried to display a carousel only in index page but doesn't work. 
I chose that the codes are not "spreaded" on the index page, they are stored in: public/carousel/carousel.php, too(not ...blade.php).

route.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')
```

HomeController.php:

```
    {
        $cats = Category::all();
        $carousel = public_path('carousel/carousel.php');
        //$carousel = storage_path('public/carousel/carousel.php');
        return view('layouts.app', compact('cats', 'carousel'));
    }
```

layouts/app.blade.php:

```
 {{-- @include('carousel/carousel');--}}

            @if($carousel)
            {{ $carousel }}
            @endif

            @yield('content')
```

Finally it displays only: `C:\wamp\www\app_name\public\carousel/carousel.php`.
Can you help me or point to another better way?

Comment: What is the content of `carousel.php`?

Comment: ```<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
   ........................
</div>```

Comment: The content of the code is exactly the same as the one in the documentation:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you are passing to the view a variable called `$carousel`, which is the path to your file, as you defined here:

```
$carousel = public_path('carousel/carousel.php');
```

This is the reason why it only displays the string. You need to get the actual content of the file:

```
$carousel = file_get_content(public_path('carousel/carousel.php'));
```

A better and more laravel-ish way to do it would be to rename the file to `carousel.blade.php`, store it into the `resources/views` folder and simply include it from your main blade file (without the need of doing anything in the controller):

```
@include('carousel')
```

If you need to display the carousel on certain pages only, you can simply pass a variable `$carousel = true` on the pages that needs to display it:

```
$carousel = true;
return view('layouts.app',compact('carousel'));
```

And in your blade view, include the carousel file only when this variables is present and is true:

```
@includeWhen(isset($carousel) && $carousel, 'carousel')
```

Comment: Thank you gbalduzzi, I did exactly what you told and it works.<br> I remains my old problem: carousel displays on the all pages but it is recommended to point only on first page(layouts.app). In the last way I did as $carousel on the HomeControlles. But: at the controller others pages I mentioned: $carousel = FALSE ...but it didn't work.<br> Can you advice me how to do it? <br> I will return to check in a few hours. Thanks for all.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the way to conditionally control the presence of the carousel from your controller

Comment: Sorry I didn't inform you that I use Laravel 5.2 that has not @includeWhen() directive. Can you help me what can I do to display carousel only on the main page not other pages. Thank you.

Comment: `@if(isset($carousel) && $carousel) @include('carousel') @endif`

Comment: Sorry, how can I mark the question, where is that place? Thx

Comment: At the left of the answer there is a big number with two arrow: one up and one down. You can use the up arrow to upvote an answer that you think correctly answer the questions or the down arrow to downvote an unappropriate or flat wrong answer. In your own questions, under the arrows you also can select a check sign to mark the questions as accepted.

Comment: I think I did it. You can let me know if there is anything else to do.